# ExtJs 4 - Drag from Tree to "empty" tree

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

Having a problem with ExtJS when it comes to dragging from a tree to another tree.

I have one tree, sourceTree, that has all the elements available to drag from.

I have another tree, targetTree that will hopefully contain all the elements dragged (selected) from the source tree.

```
var sourceStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    model: 'MyTreeModel',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: '/some_action_that_returns_tree_json',
        extraParams: { /*extra params*/
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: function (o) {
                if (o.children == null) {
                    return o.children;
                } else {
                    return o;
                }
            }
        }
    },
    folderSort: true
});
```

the source tree is defined as:

```
{
    xtype: 'treepanel',
    flex: 5,
    iconCls: 'myiconcls',
    border: true,
    store: formstore,
    loadMask: true,
    rootVisible: false,
    title: 'Source',
    bodyStyle: 'font-style:bold',
    viewConfig: {
        plugins: {
            ptype: 'treeviewdragdrop',
            appendOnly: true
        }
    }
}
```

So I have a source tree I can drag from.

The target tree is defined as:

```
{
     xtype: 'treepanel',
     flex: 5, iconCls: 'mytreecls',
     border: true, 
     store: emptystore,
     rootVisible: false,
     title: 'Selected', 
     bodyStyle: 'font-style:bold',
     viewConfig: {
        emptyText: '',
        plugins: {
           ptype: 'treeviewdragdrop',
           allowContainerDrop: true,
           appendOnly: true
        },
        listeners: {
            drop: function (node, data, model, dropPosition, opts) {
                console.log(node);
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

The first problem I have is how can I define an empty treestore with a single root node that will call the proxy url if the data for the node is not loaded.

The source tree will load leaf nodes dynamically, if I drag and add them to the target tree I want to keep that functionality.

I've tried lots of ways to set default root node - none of which I've been able to get working.

```
var emptystore= Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    model: 'TreeModel',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: '/some_action_that_returns_tree_json',
        extraParams: { ... },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: { text:"My Root",...} // doesn't work, presumably becuase the ajax call overwrite it?
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The end result should be a source tree that I can drag from into another tree. I don't want to remove the dragged node which I think is controlled by `appendOnly` property of `treeviewdragdrop`. I was trying to make it so I could handle the drop on the panel/container by setting `allowContainerDrop` to true.

To be honest this is my first endeavour into ExtJS D&D so any help appreciated.  I've obviously read the tutorial but cannot find my on tree to tree D&D.

Thanks in advance,

Sam